# ftplib, socket.sendall() ingores newline character

Tags: python, sockets, ftp, newline, ftplib

I wrote a function `append_line()` in ftplib (based on storelines()):

```
def append_line(self, cmd, string):
    self.voidcmd('TYPE A')
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
    conn.sendall(string)
    conn.close()

    return self.voidresp()
```

When I call:

```
ftp.append_line("APPE " + "Text.dat", "This is my string\n\n")
```

it will append the string to the mentioned file, but ignores the newline. So, `socket.sendall` is ignoring the character `\n`.

How can I properly update the file with a newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a different problem.  When I try to sendall with your string, it appears to work:

Client code:

```
    from socket import *
    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost", 6789))
    string = "This is my string\n\nAFTER_IT"
    s.sendall(string)
```

Server code:

```
    from socket import *
    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("", 6789))
    s.listen(8)
    (c, a) = s.accept()
    data=c.recv(1000)
    data # Displays 'This is my string\n\nAFTER_IT'
```

Comment: You are right. Problem is server used for my tests, it works under Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try sending `"\r\n\r\n"` instead of `"\n\n"`.